# Excel VBA, colour mandatory field (cell) if there is no entry and show message box

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form on an Excel sheet that has two mandatory cells which are often left incompleted by users. I have the following code which won't allow the user to save the sheet if the cells are not completed, will highlight them in red and display a message box:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

ok As Boolean
Dim xlSht As Worksheet
OK = False

Set xlSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Changes Form")

'Cell 1
If xlSht.Range("B13") = "" Then
    xlSht.Range("B13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ok = True
Else
    xlSht.Range("B13").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    ok = False

If xlSht.Range("E13") = "" Then
    xlSht.Range("E13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ok = True
Else
    xlSht.Range("E13").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    ok = False

End If

End If

If OK = True Then
MsgBox "Please review the highlighted cells and ensure the fields are populated."
Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

The code works however if there are no entries in both cells then it only colours cell B13. I think once the 'ok = True' bit of the code runs for B13, it skips the rest of the code to the end. I am unsure how to amend it so that both cells will be highlighted.

I thought about alerting the user through Data Validation however I have a listbox in both cells so I am not sure if it is still possible that way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with the below. If the first value is empty then you are missing the logic for the second. Also, no need to set to false if there is a value. Final thing I changed was your "ok" boolean to cellsNotPopulated so its more readable.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim xlSht As Worksheet
Dim cellsNotPopulated As Boolean
cellsNotPopulated = False

Set xlSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Changes Form")

    With xlSht

        If .Range("B13") = "" Then
            .Range("B13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            cellsNotPopulated = True
        Else
            .Range("B13").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If

        If .Range("E13") = "" Then
            .Range("E13").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            cellsNotPopulated = True
        Else
            .Range("E13").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If

    End With

    If cellsNotPopulated = True Then
        MsgBox "Please review the highlighted cells and ensure the fields are populated."
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```