# Mandatory fields red. Now how to save?

Tags: vba, excel

What it does: Requires fields from users. Blocks user from saving if specific fields are missing. Turns those fields red until saved correctly.

What I need: Well, how the hell am I supposed to save this...

What I would like: Since the worksheet is blank. I cannot save. and required fields are red. EVEN if I could save I would LIKE the cells to be on no fill until I roll it out.

[View Original Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529234/excel-vba-colour-mandatory-field-cell-if-there-is-no-entry-and-show-message-b)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim xlSht As Worksheet
Dim cellsNotPopulated As Boolean
cellsNotPopulated = False

Set xlSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1st Call")

    With xlSht

        If .Range("F7") = "" Then
            .Range("F7").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            cellsNotPopulated = True
        Else
            .Range("F7").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    End With

    If cellsNotPopulated = True Then
        MsgBox "Please review the highlighted cells and ensure the fields are populated."
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you check another value, so If .Range("F7") = "" and .Range("G7")<> ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in the middle of development and want to "break the rules" and save your current efforts, then in a standard module:

```
Sub MyPrivateSave()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Of course, when you finish development, you would remove this little "save tool" before you send the workbook out to the users.

Comment: or add as the first line if environ("Username")=your username then exit sub

Answer (score 1):

or add as the first line `if environ("Username")=your username then exit sub`

Comment: This makes the most sense, but I'm having trouble implementing this code. Should I ask a separate question or can I post it here?

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: It seems when I add this code, it does not actually Exit the sub, but continues to the next line.